# automatically run "remove duplicates" on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below mentioned code works well with "Workbook_BeforeSave"but I realized, that if user press save twice code paste the walues twice. So I need to run "remove duplicates" just before closing the Proposal_Admin.xlsm after last paste. Could you please kindly help me about that.

Thanks & Regards.

```
Sub CopyToOtherCell()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Integer, erow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 12).Value = Date Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Murat\Documents\Teklifler\Proposal_Admin.xlsm"
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AdminSheet").Activate
        erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just look to see if the workbook has been saved?

If ThisWorkbook.Saved then
  'Blah blah...
end if